# What are the values of the parameters p and q?

Tags: polynomials

The remainder of the division of the polynomial $$W(x)=2x^{4}+px^{3}+9x^{2}+qx+5$$ by the polynomial
$$P(x)=2x-2$$ is equal to $10$. The remainder of the division of $W(x)$ by the polynomial $$Q(x)=x+1$$
is $22$.

What are the values of the parameters $p$ and $q$?

After deriving the equation $$-p-q=6$$ by using $$W(-1)=22$$, I am unable to solve the problem

Comment: Where is this question from? What’s your progress on it? Where did you get stuck? Please edit the post to include this. Otherwise your post might get downvoted and closed very quickly, unfortunately.

Comment: consider the possibility that the problem has a family of solutions instead of a unique solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rewrite as below and solve the system of equation $p,q$

you may know ,if the remainder of the division of the polynomial $X(x)$ by the polynomial $P(x)$ is $10 $,it can be write as $$W(x)=P(x)R_{emainder}(x)+10$$so put $2x-2=0 \to x=1 $and you will have $$W(1)=(2x-2)R_{emainder}(x)+10|_{x=1} \\ \to W(1)=0R_{emainder}(1)+10$$ also for $Q(x)$ you have  $$W(x)=Q(x)R'_{emainder}(x)+22|_{x=-1}\\ \to W(-1)=Q(-1)R'_{emainder}(-1)+22$$  and finally : $$2x^{4}+px^{3}+9x^{2}+qx+5|_{x=1}=10\\2x^{4}+px^{3}+9x^{2}+qx+5|_{x=-1}=22$$ can you take over  ?

Comment: Did you mean to write Quotient instead of Remainder in the equations?

Comment: @Haris : yes ,of course.